# How do i implement i18next function in my carousel section?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using carousel as my page banner which include image, title and subtitle, when i use i18next to translate the webpage language how do i also change the title and subtitle to the other languange? below is the example code:

carousel.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Carousel.css";
import { images } from "../Helpers/CarouselData";


function Carousel() {
  const [currImg, setCurrImg] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="carousel">
      <div
        className="carouselInner"
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${images[currImg].img})` }}
      >
        <div
          className="left"
          onClick={() => {
            currImg > 0 && setCurrImg(currImg - 1);
          }}
        >
          
        </div>
        <div className="center">
          <h1>{images[currImg].title}</h1>
          <p>{images[currImg].subtitle}</p>
        </div>
        <div
          className="right"
          onClick={() => {
            currImg < images.length - 1 && setCurrImg(currImg + 1);
          }}
        >
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Carousel;
```

carouseldata.js

```
import City from "../Images/city.jpg";
import Salvador from "../Images/salvador.jpg";
import Ubc from "../Images/ubc.jpg";

export const images = [
  {
    title: "Salvador, Brazil",
    subtitle: "The Best City in the World",
    img: Salvador,
  },
  {
    title: "UBC (Vancouver)",
    subtitle: "The University of British Columbia",
    img: Ubc,
  },
];
```

Lastly i am using `const { t , i18n} = useTranslation();` to label on the words that need to make changes by`{t("something")}` .

Answer (score 0):

creating the images array needs to be done in the render loop, there you can call the t function for the titles..: